# Can't intent in new activitys java

Tags: java

I'm creating a file explorer synchronize with an ftp directory. I have recently adapted my app to work with both internal and external storage, and then I encounter an embarrassing issue. When I try to open a file using this function to intent a new activity:

```
private fun openFile(file: File) {
        val myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

        val mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(file.extension)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            val fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.toString() + ".provider", file)
            intent.setDataAndType(fileURI, mimeType)
        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType)
        }
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No app found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

Comment: In `opt_A()` after `sourceFile >> taxPayers;` you making one pass over `taxPayerr` but only comparing `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)` to `salesStaff[6]` (which only has **five** valid indexes `0 - 5`). So you are invoking undefined behavior by referencing `salesStaff` beyond your data. (out of bounds)

Comment: So what should i do to get the wanted output?

Comment: @Happyman Only you can answer that, because you're the one who wrote `salesStaff[6]` with no documentation about what it's supposed to do. That array index does not exist. If you were expecting the _last_ element of the array, it's `salesStaff[5]` because arrays are indexed starting from zero. If you're not convinced, write down the numbers 0 through to 5 and count them.

Comment: Im trying to compare taxPayers.salesstaff(i) and salesStaff[] array together. Then finding which salesstaff data doesnt contain a element from the salesStaff[] array. But also allowing blank data points as valid. But i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a more complex comparison than you are doing. You have two primary conditions:

1. Is `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)` empty? (if so, you are done); or
2. Does each of the `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)` components, e.g. `staff1:staff2:...` appear in the `salesStaff[]` array?

It is this second condition that is a *many-to-many* relationship that has many subconditions. In order to make this determination, you must separate the `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)` entry on `':'` (much like you did input from your data file on `','`). Then you must loop over each entry and compare the entry against each in the `salesStaff[]` array. If ONE of the entries in `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)` does not match ANY of the entries in the `salesStaff[]` array. then you have a bad entry.

You can use a couple of `bool` flags to help you work through the checks. One way to do that is:

```cpp
void opt_A()
{
    std::ifstream sourceFile(ffname);

    if (!sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "No file found, please check for files again" << endl;
        return;
    }

    string salesStaff[] = { "Brad", "Janet", "Dr Scott", 
                            "Rifraf", "Nell", "Eddie" };
    size_t nsstaff = sizeof salesStaff / sizeof *salesStaff;
    TaxPayers taxPayers{};
    sourceFile >> taxPayers;
    int x = 0;

    /* output list heading before loop */
    cout << "Audit Report" << '\n' <<
            "-------------------" << '\n' <<
            "File: " << ffname << "\n\n";
    
    /* loop over each taxpayer */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < taxPayers.taxPayers.size(); ++i)
    {
        bool nomatch = false;   /* flag, no match for non-empty entry */
        
        /* only check salesstaff if not empty */
        if (!taxPayers.salesstaff(i).empty())
        {
            /* instringstream to split taxPayers.salesstaff on ':' */
            istringstream iss {taxPayers.salesstaff(i)};
            std::string staff{};    /* temporary for each taxpayer staff */
            
            /* loop over each taxpayer.salesstaff staff1:staff2:... entry */
            while (getline (iss, staff, ':'))
            {   
                bool matched = false;  /* is entry matched in salesStaff[] */
                
                /* loop over each valid salesStaff */
                for (size_t j = 0; j < nsstaff; j++)
                {
                    /* if staff matches valid salesStaff */
                    if (staff == salesStaff[j]) {
                        matched = true;  /* set found flag true */
                        break;
                    } 
                }
                
                /* after looping over all, check if no match found */
                if (!matched)
                {
                    nomatch = true;   /* set nomatch flag */
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (nomatch)  /* only print details if no match for salesstaff enty */
        {
          cout << "Account Details    : " << taxPayers.showinfo(i) << '\n' <<
                  "Details            : " << taxPayers.salesstaff(i) << "\n\n";
          x++;
        }
    }
    
    /* output summary after loop */
    cout << "Total count of bad data found: " << (x) << "\n\n";
}
```

(**note:** above the heading and summary data go outside the loop unless you want that printed for each bad record -- which doesn't seem correct given the summary line)

Also note, there are many more ways you can do this. You can reduce the number of loops and avoid splitting `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)` by looping over each in the `salesStaff[]` array and using `.substr()` to determine if that staff occurs as one of the parts of `taxPayers.salesstaff(i)`. How you want to do it is up to you.

Also note, as I explained in your last question, you need to **validate** each input.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in my file `dat/taxpayers.txt`, running the program you would get:

```
$ ./bin/taxpayercheck
Audit Report
-------------------
File: dat/taxpayers.txt

Account Details    : 10011265 Mr Alexander Marshall Chemicals Ltd
Details            : Eddie:rippa mate!:Brad:

Total count of bad data found: 1
```

Let me know if you have further questions.